# Bulma cards changing width when resizing window

Tags: html, css, responsive, bulma

Cards when window is zoomed out
[image: Cards when window is zoomed out]

Cards when zoomed in

[image: Cards when zoomed in]

Is there any way to make the cards not change width when resizing the window with bulma?

```
   <div class="container">
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="column center">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-content columns is-multiline pr-2 pl-2">
                    <div class="column is-12"></div>
                    <div class="column is-12"></div>
                    <div class="column is-12"></div>
                    <div class="is-block column is-12"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a fixed width on the card with CSS, but then you are kinda going against what Bulma wants you to do (keep everything responsive) and it may break your columns.

I think your best bet would be to include some responsive column classes, so that you can specify the width according to the screen size. Untested, but just as an example:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="columns">
    <div class="column center is-three-quarters-mobile is-two-thirds-tablet is-half-desktop">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content columns is-multiline pr-2 pl-2">
                <div class="column is-12"></div>
                <div class="column is-12"></div>
                <div class="column is-12"></div>
                <div class="is-block column is-12"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[More on Bulma responsive columns](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/responsiveness/)